# laravel 4 unit testing on windows keeps giving error

Tags: windows, unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4

I have a Laravel 4 installation right out of the box. I am running Windows 8 64 bit with PHP 5.5, Apache 2.2 through XAMPP.

When I run `phpunit` I get the standard laravel error page `Whoops, looks like something went wrong.` and right above it I see `PHPUnit 3.8-dev by Sebastian Bergmann. Configuration read from C:\project\phpunit.xml The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.`

If I delete file `app/tests/ExampleTest.php` then `phpunit` seems to work and I get

```
PHPUnit 3.8-dev by Sebastian Bergmann.
Configuration read from C:\project\phpunit.xml
The Xdebug extension is not loaded. No code coverage will be generated.
Time: 232 ms, Memory: 2.75Mb
←[30;43mNo tests executed!←[0m
```

app/tests/ExampleTest.php

```
<?php

class ExampleTest extends TestCase {

  /**
   * A basic functional test example.
   *
   * @return void
   */
  public function testBasicExample()
  {
    $crawler = $this->client->request('GET', '/');
    $this->assertTrue($this->client->getResponse()->isOk());
  }

}
```

app/tests/TestCase.php

```
<?php

class TestCase extends Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\TestCase {

  /**
   * Creates the application.
   *
   * @return Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernelInterface
   */
  public function createApplication()
  {
    $unitTesting = true;

    $testEnvironment = 'testing';

    return require __DIR__.'/../../bootstrap/start.php';
  }

}
```

Comment: can you view the home page in the browser ok? have you turned debugging to 'true' to see what the actual error is?

Comment: Hi The Shift Exchange, I think I just found what's causing the problem I'm just not sure why. It's the basset module https://github.com/jasonlewis/basset/issues/204